# After aliasing ssh, can't run an explicit ssh command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh, alias

I have an alias for ssh'ing to my linux box from my mac machine. 
But I am noticing something very weird, or may be I am being stupid.

When I use the alias it works, but when I use what the alias stands for it does not work. For example

```
bos-mp9ps:~ xyz$ alias ssh
alias ssh='ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1'

bos-mp9ps:~ xyz$ ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1
bash: xyz@bos-lpaw1: command not found

bos-mp9ps:~ xyz$ ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-65-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

429 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

New release '16.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

You have new mail.
Last login: Tue Jan  3 10:29:27 2017 from 172.19.37.47
xyz@bos-lpaw1:~$
```

Also I am able to ssh into my linux box from private home networks, but not from public networks such as starbucks etc. Do you know if I have to change anything for this ?

```
My /etc/hosts on linux machine looks like this:
bos-mp9ps:~ xyz$ cat /etc/hosts
# BEGIN hosts added by Pulse
23.79.238.45   vpn.company.com
# END hosts added by Pulse
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

When I use my linux's box's IP address to login it does not help and it brings me to same position

```
bos-mp9ps:~ xyz$ command ssh xyz@172.19.37.47
The authenticity of host '172.19.37.47 (172.19.37.47)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:MQwHj9JTw5d2Vzbz5h5hw2KxmhKmREVGIcrY+PrBxQc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '172.19.37.47' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Last login: Thu Dec 29 15:18:10 2016
Agent pid 971
bos-mp9ps:~ xyz$
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: public places could block the ports, did u check for that?

Comment: what happens if you call ssh only? what happens when u call the ssh without -A and with a full ip adress? is ur linux box only in ur local network?

Comment: Please try to be sure that your title is clear enough to uniquely and specifically identify your problem. Part of the point of the site is to build up a knowledge base of questions and answers -- having hundreds of questions titled "ssh question" means that nobody else can figure out if one of those questions already asks (and answers) their existing problem.

Comment: Beyond that, as a note, using `set -x` to have the shell log every command it ran (after alias expansion, functions, etc) would have enabled you to find this problem yourself.

Comment: Hi @jonas_toth thanks for bringing that point. How to check for that if ports are blocked  ?

Comment: @jonas_toth I edited my post to have what happens when u call the ssh without -A and with a full ip adress. What do you mean by "is ur linux box only in ur local network"?
It is my company's pc which I login to to work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank for pointing that out I should have been more implicit in the title. Will remember from next time :)

Comment: If you're still editing, follow my suggestion: Run `set -x`, then compare `ssh` and `ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1`, and compare the output. The immediate cause should be obvious. :)

Comment: @hitman99 yes, i mean the physical location. By accessing it from another network, there has to be done routing. Sometimes networks dont let you pass for specific protocol (e.g. ssh). Do you have an vpn into your companies network? Use this if you are not in your company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The others have answered how do fix your alias, but I think the best way of doing this is actually to dispense with aliases altogether and use the ssh configuration file, which is usually in `~/.ssh/config`. To match what your alias does, you would put something like this in it (assuming it's using OpenSSH or something similar):

```
Host linux
  User xyz
  HostName bos-lpaw1
  ForwardAgent yes
```

With this in place, you would log in to the computer like this:

```
$ ssh linux
```

(you can give it any host alias you want, it doesn't have to be "linux").

Why should you do it this way? There are several advantages:

1. Since you're not hardcoding which host you're logging into like your original alias did, you are free to log into multiple different computers (but you can get this by making one alias for each target computer, so the alias method can also support this).
2. Host aliases described in `.ssh/config` are also recognized by `rsync` and `scp`. So you are automatically able to do stuff like `rsync a.txt linux:b.txt` to copy `a.txt` to the linux computer and naming it `b.txt`.

To be able to ssh into your computer from public networks, you need a way to get the IP address of your computer. You can either try to set this up using DNS (though that can be a hassle) or if your IP doesn't change very often you can just hard-code it. Of course, if you use [Network Adress Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) you will probably need to set up port forwarding on your modem/router, so that incoming connections to your global address get forwarded to the correct local computer.

Comment: thanks @amaurea for an amazing answer.
it works like this. 
My linux box's IP is static.  Can you tell me where and how can I hardcode it and how should I use it afterwards? 
I tried doing that in my etc/hosts but each time, I see it is wiped. Does that mean I have to do it again ?

Comment: If you search google for "what is my ip", it should give you your public IP address. Let's say the result is 1.2.3.4. Then, you could replace `HostName bos-lpaw1` with `HostName 1.2.3.4` in the ssh configuration file (though that might not work if you're on your own local network). Alternatively you could put it in `/etc/hosts`, but you must the ensure that NetworkManager or other programs don't overwrite it. How to do this depends on exactly what is overwriting the file. See e.g. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/382744/how-to-make-changes-to-mac-etc-hosts-permanent).

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

`ssh` is aliased to `'ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1'`

so

`ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1`

is converted to

`ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1 -A xyz@bos-lpaw1`

So this command is trying to execute the "command" `xyz@bos-lpaw1` by the user `xyz` on the server `bos-lpaw1`.

## Solution

#### Another alias

Replace
`alias ssh='ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1'`

with

`alias sshlpaw='ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1'`

`ssh` is a **very** important program, overriding it with an alias isn't a good idea.

#### Prevent alias with command

For the cases where you need the usual ssh without alias, you can type :

`command ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1`

in your terminal.

#### use .ssh/config

see @amaurea's excellent answer.

Comment: Ahh,That was silly of me.
I did not think of that. Thanks :)

Comment: However I did not get your point of "command ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1"?
Do you mean I have to add this in my bash_profile ?
what is command here

Comment: @hitman99, no, on the command line. `command` prevents aliases (or functions) from being expanded, meaning that `command ssh ...` runs the real ssh command, whereas `ssh ...` can run an alias or function named `ssh`.

Comment: BTW, since aliases aren't inherited by subshells or enabled by default in noninteractive interpreters (such as those invoked to run scripts), I wouldn't be so worried about breaking other scripts (unless they're sourced into the OP's interactive shell). An exported function would be a higher risk for that. Though I do fully agree that what the OP is trying to do is a horrible idea.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, `ssh() { if (( $# == 0 )); then ssh -A xyz@bos-lpaw1; else command ssh "$@"; fi; }` doesn't strike me as breaking very many things, since it only takes any action with no arguments given (thus, in a case where usage would otherwise be invalid.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks got it.